# Post-apocalyptic novel like Stephen King's "The Stand": survivors of a deadly virus have a cocoon-like mask

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this novel in the early '90s, and though I couldn't swear to its original publication date, it did have some fairly recent culture references. As I recall it was thematically similar to *The Stand*, with a virus having reduced the population of the world to a sliver of its previous numbers.

In this novel, however, everyone who survived had their head/face covered by a hard cocoon-like mask, which when it molted off would reveal a new face. They then divided into factions preparing for a final conflict.

I've tried searching both here and the wider internet, but as you can imagine keywords such as "virus" "mask", and "post-apocalyptic" turn up more daily news articles than fiction right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible you are misremembering [*Swan Song*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swan_Song_(McCammon_novel)) (1987), by Robert R. McCammon.

After a nuclear war, people who have been victims of flash burns and radiation poisoning develop a condition called "Job's Mask" which encases their heads in a tumor-like growth.  "Swan", the heroine, can mystically cure this affliction, in a metaphor of rebirth.

Comment: That mostly fits, including my faded memory that their new faces reflect their inner nature. Thanks!

Comment: It's an interesting work in the sense that it contains a lot of set pieces and striking imagery that stick with you even after you forget the full story.  It's kind of like *A Boy and His Dog* in that respect.